# Access set-cookie header of ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is it possible to access set-cookie header of an ajax response?

The response has other access control headers correctly set, but I can't seem to be able to access all the response headers.

I tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:endpointURL,
   xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
   data: Data2Send,
   success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        var cookiez=XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
        alert(cookiez);
   }
  });
```

The alert returns null.
Thanks!

Comment: if it's not an `httpOnly` protected  cookie can get it from `document.cookie`

Comment: @charlietfl: Not if it’s cross-origin either, which the question seems to imply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX Reponse Set Cookie Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968611/jquery-ajax-reponse-set-cookie-header)

Comment: If it is cross domain as @Ryan points out.... why would you need to access it anyway? Also are you sending `withCredentials` header?

Comment: it's cross-origin and yes I am sending the withCredentials header.

Comment: The problem is that I can't access the Set-Cookie header at all